# How to set the toggled colour for a ToggleButton in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, colors, uwp

So this is probably a really simple answer. In my UWP app I've tried to start using the built-in Windows controls instead of my own buttons made from Borders around Textblocks. I'm doing this because it's simpler, but most importantly I need an easy to use toggle button.

I've learned about CommandBar and AppBarToggleButton and these seem to be exactly what I want. I'm able to set the background colour of the CommandBar just fine, but when toggled the AppBarToggleButton is always the user's accent colour. I need to be able to define it to match my app's branding (green). I have a feeling it requires me using some sort of theme as it's not in the xaml object's Brush properties menu, but I'm lost from then on out.

So this is my code, though it's very basic.

```
<CommandBar Background="{StaticResource MapButtonsBackgroundAcrylic}">
    <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="tog_view_mode" Icon="View" Label="View Mode" Foreground="White"/>
    <AppBarSeparator Foreground="White"/>
    <AppBarToggleButton x:Name="tog_edit_mode" Icon="Edit" Label="Edit Mode" Foreground="White"/>
</CommandBar>
```

And this is what it gives me. My user accent colour is that blue. Also the change to black text isn't good.

[image: Toggle Button Colours]

As I'll have several toggles in my app, I'd like to either make a single style that I can assign them, or maybe change the accent colour that the app see's? I'm not sure what the correct procedure is here as I'm new to modifying built-in controls.

So I need a way for, when toggled,

- The background to be green, say #FF008000
- The foreground to be white.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the style template for the `AppBarToggleButton` to achieve this.
To do this you need to right click on your **AppBarToggleButton > Edit template > Edit a copy**.

Then add the relevant code to the visual state. In your case the visual state is "**Checked**".

```
    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                  <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedHighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowCheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Your color here(green)"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowContentRoot" />
                  </Storyboard>
         </VisualState>
```

Hope this helps.. please feel free to ask any questions that you might have..

Comment: +1 on this one. You can also use `{TemplateBinding <Property Name>}` to access any properties from the unchecked state to persist them on the checked state.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `AppBarToggleButtonBackground` and other brushes in your `App.xaml` (if you want to apply to the whole app), in the `Resources` section of your page (if you want to apply to a specific page) or the same inside the actual toggle button (if you want to apply to a single button). The available resource keys are listed in the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbartogglebutton?view=winrt-19041)